# Mongoid insert embedded document to many documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Let's say, I have two models

```
class User
  embeds_many :notifications
  field :age, type :Integer

class Notification
  embedded_in :user
  field :message, type: String
```

I want to create notification and add it to all users, matching specific criteria. All I came up with is:

```
notification = Notification.new
notification.message = "Hello"
User.where(:age.ge => 18).push(:notifications, notification)
```

But this won't work. Any idea?

UPD: I know, there's a way to make it work like so:

```
users = User.where(:age.ge => 18)
users.each do |user|
  notification = Notification.new
  notification.message = "Hello"
  user.notifications << notification
  user.save
end
```

But this seems ugly and inefficient code.

UPD2: Finally, this code works, directly working with driver, as Winfield stated:

```
users = User.where(:age.ge => 18)
notification = Notification.new
notification.message = "Hello"
User.collection.update(users.selector, {'$push' => {notifications: notification.as_document}}, multi: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do this at the raw Mongo Driver level:

```
db.users.update({}, { $push: { notifications: { message: 'Hello!' } } })
```

However, if your goal is to accomplish a mass-messaging feature, you might be better off making a special collection for these Notifications and having your application code pull system-wide notifications and user-targeted notifications.

Having to update every single user object in your system to send a mass message is not a scalable design.

Comment: The thing is I have a bit more complex model, having more than just one field. I want to threat those embedded documents as usual Mongoid::Document representatives and denormalize database so each user can handle them separately. Let's imagine, that there are _lots_ of notifications, added by different criterias so I don't want fetch all of them, when getting ones for the user.